# Parrot Security OS ISO in VirtualBox asks for password when booting in live mode

Tags: passwords, parrot-os

I made a bootable USB flash drive of Parrot Security OS ISO and am using it in VirtualBox on a PC.

But it is asking me for password when I select live mode when it starts. Why?

How can I boot this or is there a default password?

Answer (score 2):

In live mode (everything is run in RAM).
The default username is "user" and the default password is "toor".

See docs: https://docs.parrotlinux.org/library/what-is-live-mode/

FAQs: https://docs.parrotlinux.org/faq/

If you'd like to change those, drop into root w/ "sudo su" and use “passwd” & “passwd user” to set the root & user passwords respectively. 
as per s1udge's answer in this thread: https://community.parrotlinux.org/t/cant-get-su/1350/4

Answer (score 1):

However it is no longer true and in newer versions like for example Parrot Security 5.3, which is the freshest right now - username/password are parrot/parrot

Comment: Hello, what is no longer true? You're answering the question, not the other answer, keep that in mind when answering please.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192930)